# EntityFrameWork - I need to get a value from another table

Tags: c#, entity

So, i need to get a value ( cNIF ) inside  table ( projetos ) and i dont really know how to get there

So far i have this:

[SC3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJtjv.png)

[SC2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XUBo.png)

[screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTVfj.png)

im using this code for add new client and i have a dropdownlist select the client with name and nif but in projectos.aspx nothing happens and i dont know what to do :(

```
protected void btadd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            using (MyMoneyEntities context = new MyMoneyEntities())
            {

                project p = new project();
                p.pName = txtNome.Text;
                p.createdOn = DateTime.Now.Date;


                context.projects.Add(p);
                context.SaveChanges();

                Response.Redirect("projetos.aspx");


            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            utils.pnlResultadoStyle(ref divResultado, 2);
            lblResultado.Text = ex.Message + " | " + ex.InnerException;
        }
    }
```

> This is my projectos.aspx

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdLista" runat="server" EmptyDataText="Não existem registos a apresentar."
            Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4"
            ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" PagerSettings-Mode="NextPreviousFirstLast"
            PagerSettings-NextPageText="Seguinte" PagerSettings-PreviousPageText="Anterior"
            PagerSettings-Position="TopAndBottom" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="80" >
            <RowStyle BackColor="#f1f1f1" Height="30px" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="pId" HeaderText="#" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Nome">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbActualizar" PostBackUrl='<%# string.Concat("projetos-update.aspx?id=", Eval("pid").ToString()) %>'
                            runat="server" ToolTip="Editar"><%# Eval("pname").ToString() %>
                        </asp:LinkButton>
                  </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>  
                <asp:BoundField DataField="cNIF" HeaderText="NIF Cliente" /> 
                <asp:BoundField DataField="createdOn" HeaderText="Criado Em" /> 
                <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False" ItemStyle-Width="20px">
                    <ItemTemplate>                            
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbDelete" Text="Apagar" runat="server"
                            OnClientClick="return confirm('Tem a certeza que deseja apagar?');" ToolTip="Apagar">
                            <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
                        </asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

> in here im loading both grids clients and projetos...

```
 public partial class projetos : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            loadData();
        }
    }

    private void loadData()
    {
        try
        {
            using (MyMoneyEntities context = new MyMoneyEntities())
            {
                grdLista.DataSource = context.clients.ToList();
                grdLista.DataSource = context.projects.ToList();
                grdLista.DataBind();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and is cNIF available as a property of (project? client?). Why do you set the dataSource of grdLista twice?

Comment: cNIF is a property of client and i want show cNIF in project.aspx but i dont know how... bc i think with that could work but didnt :/